# Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate [SWIFTUI]

Tags: binding, swiftui, state, swift5

today I'm trying to set a value into my `@state` variable currentConfigurations. I use an `API` to fill that variable, the thing is when I try to make this using `onAppear()` method I got this error:

**Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate**

I don't know how to "cast" my object to avoid this mistakes

```
struct PreferencesView: View {
    let settingsService = SettingsService()
    @State private var currentConfigurations : Settings? = nil
    @State private var childIsPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            VStack(spacing:0){

             HStack{

                Text("notificationsConfiguration")
                Spacer()
                Button(action:{
                    self.childIsPresented = true
                }){
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                }




            }
            .padding()
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$childIsPresented){
                NotificationsView(isPresented: self.$childIsPresented, currentConfigurations: self.$currentConfigurations)
            }

                Spacer()
            }


        }.onAppear(){
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            let userId = defaults.integer(forKey: "userId")
            self.settingsService.getSettings(id: userId){(settings) in
                self.currentConfigurations = settings
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `getSettings` method

```
func getSettings(id: Int, completionHandler: @escaping (Settings)->Void){
    var settingsData: Settings! = nil
    AF.request(SettingsRouter.getById(id: id)).responseJSON{ response in
        switch(response.result){
        case .success(let response):
            print(response)
            let dict = (response as? [String : Any])!
            if let json = dict["data"] as? [String: Any] {

                if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json , options: .prettyPrinted)
                {
                    do {
                        let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
                        print(jsonString)
                        settingsData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Settings.self, from: jsonData)
                        print("Object Converted:")
                    } catch {
                        print("Parsing Failed: ", error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }else{
                print("Credenciales Incorrectas")
            }
            completionHandler(settingsData)

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completionHandler(settingsData)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you show signature of `getSettings`?

Comment: sure! let me update this post

Comment: i would recommend you post code here which a) is compilable and b) reproduces the problem, else we can just guess what your problem is....

Comment: The problem is that is not a compilable code so I can't reproduce the problem. If I try hardcoding my states it works fine but I don't need that

Comment: try to modify `getSettings` method to return the exact setting object. It's more obvious than using a closure to change self property inside the method. The thing is its hard for SwiftUI compiler to typecheck complex closures. You'd better help it by making things obvious. Other programmists will say thanx too:))

Comment: What's going to happen if I return an error? I need to cast the response, I guess